# Needed shell script modification to show IP and host DD-WRT

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, dd-wrt

I am running DD-WRT v.3.0 on my Linksys EA6500 router and I have the following script running in order to give me access to the WiFi MAC address that are currently connected to the router:

```
echo "#!/bin/ash" > /tmp/getmac.sh
echo 'echo { > /tmp/www/list.html' >>/tmp/getmac.sh
echo "for i in \$(arp | awk '{print toupper(\$4)}'); do echo \$i, >> /tmp/www/list.html; done" >>/tmp/getmac.sh
echo 'echo } >> /tmp/www/list.html' >>/tmp/getmac.sh
chmod +x /tmp/getmac.sh
/tmp/getmac.sh
```

I can visit http://192.168.1.1/user/list.html and it will show me a list of WiFi MAC address that are currently connected to the router:

Example:

```
{ 01:81:18:3d:49:5e, 04:10:87:8c:47:9a, }
```

However, I would like to modify that to also include the **IP ADDRESS** and also the **NAME OF THE DEVICE**.

I found [this](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Examples#Which_IP_addresses_and_hostnames_are_used_for_wireless_clients.3F) on the DD-WRT website but when running the command and checking the directory, I do not see it anywhere.

```
 # mkdir -p /tmp/www
 while [ 1 ];
  do
  wl assoclist | awk '{print tolower($2)}' > /tmp/assocLIST
  # echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"><b>Hostnames and IP addresses of WLAN clients</b> (last update: $(date))<p>" > /tmp/www/wlan.html
  while read assocLINE
   do
     dumpleases | awk '/'"$assocLINE"'/ {print "Hostname: " $1, "MAC: " $2, "IP: " $3}'
   # echo "<br>";
        done < /tmp/assocLIST     # >> /tmp/www/wlan.html
  sleep 10;
done;
```

I would like it to output like so:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "IP": "192.168.1.55",
        "MAC": "01:81:18:3d:49:5e",
        "HOST": "DavidsAndroidPhone"
    }, {
        "IP": "192.168.1.79",
        "MAC": "04:10:87:8c:47:9a",
        "HOST": "BobsIphone"
    }]
}
```

How can I modify my first script I posted to include the **IP** and **NAME**?

**UPDATE**

When I do the command **arp** in PuTTYtel I get the following info:

```
DD-WRT login: root
Password:
==========================================================

     ___  ___     _      _____  ______       ____  ___
    / _ \/ _ \___| | /| / / _ \/_  __/ _  __|_  / / _ \
   / // / // /___/ |/ |/ / , _/ / /   | |/ //_ <_/ // /
  /____/____/    |__/|__/_/|_| /_/    |___/____(_)___/

                       DD-WRT v3.0
                   http://www.dd-wrt.com

==========================================================


BusyBox v1.24.1 (2016-03-07 05:09:22 CET) built-in shell (ash)

root@DD-WRT:~# arp
android-17af243062d3eb6b (192.168.1.144) at 00:ae:fa:4a:3a:4c [ether]  on br0
```

So currently the script I am running (getmac.sh) looks at this and gets only this:

```
{ 00:ae:fa:4a:3a:4c, }
```

So given that, how can I modify the script to get more of the information I am looking for in the proper JSON layout?

**UPDATE 2**

Ok I have this code here:

```
arp | awk 'BEGIN { print "{" } { print "MAC:" $4 ", IP:" $2 ", HOST:" $1} END { print "}" }'
```

Which outputs the following:

```
{
MAC:00:ae:fa:4a:3a:4c, IP:(192.168.1.144), HOST:android-17af243062d3eb6b
}
```

Now given that above, how can I remove the **(** and the **)** from the IP and format it in proper JSON form? I've tried **awk -F'('** but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What are the contents of `/tmp/assocLIST`? Please edit your post to include that intermediate file used by the script.

Comment: @Anthon Oddly enough that does not exist either. Just like **/tmp/getmac.sh** wasent there until I created it. So I am guessing it creates that .sh script when I execute the script. But like i said, it doesnt show up on the file system like **getmac.sh** does.

Comment: The script should create it. Do you have the `wl` command installed? What does `wl assoclist` give when run on its own? If that doesn't produce output, it is no wonder the rest of the script doesn't either.

Comment: @Anthon Nope, not producing any output when doing that command in PuTTytel. How can I fix that?

Comment: Assuming that you are not running in client mode this should work, but I cannot test it as I have not been running dd-wrt for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this will need some work, but to start check what are the adapters with

```
ifconfig
```

Then run:

```
wl -i ethX assoclist
```

until you find the one that ddwrt is using for your wifi. You still have to mess a bit to get your exact output structure but the original script (plus -i adapter) should work.